# How can I print margin sizes fixed by geometry package other than native dimensions

Tags: margins, geometry

The native dimensions e.g., `\textwidth`, `\topmargin` can be printed by  `\printlength{\topmargin}`  like command using `printlen` package. Even they are available from layout or layouts package from the command `\layout` or `\pagevalues` `\pagediagram` commands. But, the margin values **top**, **bottom**, **left**, **right**, **vmargin**, **vmarginratio** can not be retrieved by any command. Even it is not mentioned in the log file. What is command or how can any one get the values present in a file?

Comment: There is are no lengths that hold those values so nothing to print. I do believe that there is an option to get geometry to print out most of the values it uses into the log. I should be listed in the geometry manual

Comment: You can use the `verbose` key for geometry to have dimensions in the log file.

Comment: @Bernard The parameters are *always* written in the log file. With `verbose` they're also displayed on the console during the TeX run.

Comment: @egreg: Thank you for the information! I wasn't aware of this point.